# BCM4312 802.11b/g and Scientific-linux

Tags: wifi

I have a fresh Scientific-linux 6.1 install on a Compaq 610 notebook:

```
lspci | grep Broadcom
10:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

But I can't see the wifi interface listed in "ifconfig -a".

How can I bring the wifi to life?

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the driver for the card:

```
modprobe b43
```

If you want to automatically load this every time at boot, create `/etc/sysconfig/modules/b43.modules` as

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/modprobe b43
```

And then `chmod a+x /etc/sysconfig/modules/b43.modules`

Answer (score 0):

I use CentOS, but I followed the instructions [here](http://elrepo.org/tiki/wl-kmod&highlight=broadcom) to build Broadcom support into my laptop using the proprietary drivers. Works like a charm.